# ARM Neon C: Wrong answer

Tags: c++, arm, neon

I am a beginner studying ARM neon C extensions and I am trying to vectorise a for loop given below

```
for (p = Lp [i] + 1 ; p < c [i] ; p++)
 {
      x [Li [p]] += Lx [p] * lki ;
 }
```

where x and Lx are double arrays. I modified the code as below.

```
float32x4_t Lx_vec;
float32x4_t lki_vec;
float32x4_t result_vec;

lki_vec = vdupq_n_f32(lki);/* duplicate lki in all lanes*/

for (p = Lp [i] + 1 ; p < c[i]/4 ; p+=4)
{

float lx_float[4]; 
for (int m = 0; m < 4; ++m) /* loop needed because double not supported in neon*/
{ 
   A_float[m] = (float)A[p+m]; 
}
Lx_vec = vld1q_f32(lx_float);/*vectorise subset of Lx*/

//parallel multiplication of the vectors
result_vec[p] = vmulq_f32(Lx_vec,lki_vec);

//store value to x[Li[p]]
vst1q_lane_f32(&result,result_vec,0);
x [Li [p]] += (double)result;

result = 0;
vst1q_lane_f32(&result,result_vec,1);
x [Li [p+1]] += (double)result;

result = 0;
vst1q_lane_f32(&result,result_vec,2);
x [Li [p+2]] += (double)result;

result = 0;
vst1q_lane_f32(&result,result_vec,3);
x [Li [p+3]] += (double)result;
}
```

I guess I am doing it entirely wrong as the code is giving me segmentation fault. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. Also I could not figure out another way of vectorising the loop.

I now added handling for the condition where the arrays are not a multiple of 4 in size as per suggestions in the comment as below.

```
   int loopCount = (c[i]- (Lp [i] + 1))/4;
   p = Lp [i] + 1;
   int count = 0;
   while (count<loopCount)
   {
      float lx_float[4]; 

      for (int m = 0; m < 4; ++m) /* loop needed because double not supported in neon*/
      { 
        lx_float[m] = (float)Lx[p+m]; 
      }

      Lx_vec = vld1q_f32(lx_float);/*vectorise subset of Lx*/

      //parallel multiplication of the vectors
      result_vec = vmulq_f32(Lx_vec,lki_vec);

      //store value to x[Li[p]]
      vst1q_lane_f32(&result,result_vec,0);
      x [Li [p]] -= (double)result;

      result = 0;
      vst1q_lane_f32(&result,result_vec,1);
      x [Li [p+1]] -= (double)result;

      result = 0;
      vst1q_lane_f32(&result,result_vec,2);
      x [Li [p+2]] -= (double)result;

      result = 0;
      vst1q_lane_f32(&result,result_vec,3);
      x [Li [p+3]] -= (double)result;

      count++;
      p+=4;
    }
    //normal calculation for the remaining indices
    for ( ; p < c [i] ; p++)
    {
      x [Li [p]] -= Lx [p] * lki ;
    }
```

Now the segmentation fault does not occur. But still my code is giving the wrong answer. That is the answer is different from the answer obtained before vectorisation. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens if the arrays are not a multiple of 4 in size? It would help greatly if you gave complete and compilable code example that exhibits the issue.

Comment: You aren't learning NEON instructions but intrinsics. Wrong values in NEON regusters cannot cause segmentation faults. It must be ARM's control flow which is intrinsics related.

Comment: @uesp i did not deal with the scenario where arrays are not a multiple of 4 in size. Will look into it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE sorry. I changed to neon c extensions instead of instructions in my question. I did not understand your comment. Can you make it a bit more clear.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: Wrong values in registers can definitely cause NEON instructions to fault (for example, if the pointer used by a load or store isn't aligned).  Note that these aren't in the NEON registers but the general-purpose registers used for control.

Comment: @BenVoigt can u suggest a link on how I can handle the alignment? How can I make sure the pointers are aligned?

Comment: @BenVoigt What's the point? I explicitly told "NEON registers".

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: Yes you did... but you are picking a nit that is not in the question.  The intrinsics map directly onto NEON instructions, you are complaining about nothing.

Comment: @Mia: You can use `malloc_aligned` for example.

Comment: @BenVoigt the library for malloc_aligned?

Comment: @uesp when i added the handling of arrays being not multiples of 4 as you suggested, I could get rid of the segmentation fault. Thanks for the suggestion. Even though now it is completing execution, the code is giving the wrong answer. Not the same answer as non vectorised loop. I have edited my question with my changed code.

Comment: @BenVoigt I actually gave the OP a useful hint that he should look at the flow rather than the instrinsics. What you did was just confusing him with your inappropriate and incorrect comment.

Answer (score 0):

You convert double to float, do the math with NEON, and convert back to double, right?

32bit NEON doesn't support double. Thus, the converting to float is done by the VFP, switch to NEON, do the math, switch back to VFP, convert to double and store the results.

The caveat is however, each switching wastes roughly 12 cycles. You are wasting 24 cycles/iteration which is far more than the cycles you want to have saved through the vectorization.

Now you have choice :

1. Stay away from NEON when you have to deal with double.
2. Do extremely heavy unrolling so that the 24 cycles overhead get diminished.
3. Read double as 64bit integers with NEON, do the conversions with integer bit hacking

1) is the most realistic, 2) is hardly possible with intrinsics, 3) requires expert knowledge in both NEON and IEEE754 data type.

There is no free lunch. The compiler and intrinsics don't generate optimized machine codes automatically. Intrinsics generated NEON codes are mostly crap and sometimes even buggy, and you won't find out what went wrong until you take a deeper look at the disassembly.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I wanted to stay away from neon for double but not possible as I have strict orders to find a way to optimise the code somehow. I tried telling that the vectorisation cannot be performed because of the first reason you mentioned but here the condition is such that it is assumed that I am not able to crack it because of my lack of knowledge in the field...which maybe true :( Anyway, I think it is an unrealistic goal..but may be I can try 2nd or 3rd options. Can you give any links on how they can be done? Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Then you should learn ARM assembly first. It must suck having a clueless boss.

Comment: Where there are bugs (including performance issues) with the operation of the intrinsics, they should be raised with your compiler vendor. Oftentimes the compiler can generate better code through intrinsics than assembly, as it has better visibility of register pressure, instruction scheduling, folding/inlining opportunities, Common expression elimination, etc. There will, of course, be cases where an expert beats the compiler, but the intrinsics are (bugs aside) more performance portable.

Comment: @JamesGreenhalgh No way. If someone write NEON assembly codes that's slower than those generated by intrinsics, he should quit. I've seen so many intrinsics codes that are hardly any faster than pure ARM codes due to the pipeline stalls. NEON is a heavy unit with long pipelines/latencies. You can't optimized properly with intrinsics since it starts to shuffle between registers meaninglessly once you try to unroll in order to avoid pipeline stalls.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Which is all well and good until you try to port the code to a processor for which different instruction scheduling or selection would be beneficial for avoiding pipeline stalls. At that point you necessitate re-optimizing your code, something the compiler will (assuming no bugs) try to do for you. If you are an expert, and you have sufficient micro-architectural details of your target processor, and you know your code will only ever run on one particular target processor, then you can probably beat the compiler.

Comment: @JamesGreenhalgh Which new processor? ARMv8? Do you honestly think intrinsics codes will get compiled properly for aarch64? Converting ARMv7 to ARMv8 NEON is a piece of cake. What's optimization for you? Currently I'm converting intrinsics "optimized" codes to assembly ones and my codes run 5~6 times as fast. Can you call something optimized that can be "tuned" further so that it runs five times as fast? Maybe you can optimize some simple demos like luminance calculation with intrinsics, but in real world applications, intrinsics is utterly useless.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Recall the difference between a target processor and a target architecture. In GCC -march controls the target architecture (with values like armv7-a, armv8-a, armv6), -mcpu controls the target processor (with values like cortex-a5, cortex-a7, cortex-a8, cortex-a9, cortex-a15). Moving between micro-architectures (-mcpu values) brings different pipeline characteristics. For example, some micro-architectures feature out-of-order execution units, others are strictly in order. The compiler models these differences when scheduling instructions for a given -mcpu or -mtune value.

Comment: @JamesGreenhalgh Obviously you never took a look at the disassembly. Can you read that in first place? I don't think so considering how misinformed you are. You might change the compile options as you desire, the generated codes are almost always the same. OOE doesn't matter. In-order optimized codes don't run any slower on OOE architectures. And the instruction timing characteristics don't vary that much between architecture versions. The exact cycles vary a little, but hardly anything that would force me to reschedule the instructions. Add is always faster than mul. Common sense is enough.